# Android app not having internet connection on device but works fine on emulator

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions, android-syncadapter

I am developing an android native app that uses a `SyncAdapter` to check a restful API and manipulate the local `SQLiteDatabase`  accordingly.

The app is working completely fine on emulator, but when I generate APK and install it on an android phone, the internet connection does not get established and therefore no API call is made.

Any ideas on what the issue might be? The INTERNET permission is added to my `AndroidManifest.xml` by the way.

The following is the device's LogCat:

```
12-11 04:15:28.396 2973-2973/? D/dalvikvm: Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize : 0
12-11 04:15:28.397 2973-2973/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
12-11 04:15:28.398 2973-2973/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
12-11 04:15:28.399 2973-2973/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
12-11 04:15:28.399 2973-2973/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
12-11 04:15:28.400 2973-2973/? D/dalvikvm: zygote get new systemTid : 2973
12-11 04:15:28.400 2973-2973/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-11 04:15:28.400 2973-2978/? D/dalvikvm: threadid=2: interp stack at 0x4f6a8000
12-11 04:15:28.401 2973-2979/? D/dalvikvm: threadid=3: interp stack at 0x4f7b0000
12-11 04:15:28.401 2973-2979/? D/dalvikvm: Elevating priority from 0 to -8
12-11 04:15:28.401 2973-2973/? D/jdwp: prepping for JDWP over ADB
12-11 04:15:28.401 2973-2973/? D/jdwp: ADB transport startup
12-11 04:15:28.402 2973-2980/? D/dalvikvm: threadid=4: interp stack at 0x4f8b8000
12-11 04:15:28.402 2973-2980/? D/jdwp: JDWP: thread running
12-11 04:15:28.403 2973-2980/? D/jdwp: acceptConnection
12-11 04:15:28.403 2973-2980/? D/jdwp: trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
12-11 04:15:28.403 2973-2981/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=5: interp stack at 0x545f8000
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: zygote get thread init done
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=32KB
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create new thread
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: new thread created
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: update thread list
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2982/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=6: interp stack at 0x54600000
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2982/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=6: created from interp
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: start new thread
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=32KB
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create new thread
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2982/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=6: notify debugger
12-11 04:15:28.404 2973-2982/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=6 (ReferenceQueueDaemon): calling run()
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: new thread created
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: update thread list
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2983/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=7: interp stack at 0x54708000
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2983/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=7: created from interp
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: start new thread
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=32KB
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create new thread
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: new thread created
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: update thread list
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2983/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=7: notify debugger
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2983/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=7 (FinalizerDaemon): calling run()
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2984/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=8: interp stack at 0x54810000
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2984/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=8: created from interp
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: start new thread
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2984/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=8: notify debugger
12-11 04:15:28.405 2973-2984/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=8 (FinalizerWatchdogDaemon): calling run()
12-11 04:15:28.410 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: received file descriptor 33 from ADB
12-11 04:15:28.411 2973-2985/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=9: interp stack at 0x54c16000
12-11 04:15:28.412 2973-2986/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=10: interp stack at 0x54d1e000
12-11 04:15:28.415 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-11 04:15:28.415 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-11 04:15:28.415 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000081, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-11 04:15:28.417 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-11 04:15:28.418 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x40000082, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
12-11 04:15:28.418 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3D
12-11 04:15:28.418 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-11 04:15:28.418 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000083, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-11 04:15:28.419 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-11 04:15:28.419 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000084, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-11 04:15:28.419 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-11 04:15:28.419 2973-2980/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000085, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-11 04:15:28.438 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x49
12-11 04:15:28.444 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@tech.dalvandi.dataplay1-2.apk@classes.dex
12-11 04:15:28.451 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=32KB
12-11 04:15:28.451 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: create new thread
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: new thread created
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: update thread list
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2987/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: interp stack at 0x551d5000
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2987/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: created from interp
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: start new thread
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2987/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: notify debugger
12-11 04:15:28.452 2973-2987/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: threadid=11 (Stetho-Listener): calling run()
12-11 04:15:28.454 2973-2987/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/stetho: Listening on @stetho_tech.dalvandi.dataplay1_devtools_remote
12-11 04:15:28.466 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
12-11 04:15:28.466 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16088: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
12-11 04:15:28.466 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16090: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16092: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16096: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-11 04:15:28.467 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.470 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-11 04:15:28.470 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 744: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-11 04:15:28.470 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.472 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-11 04:15:28.472 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 766: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-11 04:15:28.472 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
12-11 04:15:28.480 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
12-11 04:15:28.480 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 511: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
12-11 04:15:28.480 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.480 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
12-11 04:15:28.480 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 518: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
12-11 04:15:28.480 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 519: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 520: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 522: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 524: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalCacheDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 526: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 528: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 532: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.481 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getObbDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getObbDirs
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 534: Landroid/content/Context;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 545: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 560: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
12-11 04:15:28.482 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.494 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.516 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
12-11 04:15:28.516 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16558: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-11 04:15:28.516 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.525 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
12-11 04:15:28.525 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 520: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
12-11 04:15:28.525 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.531 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
12-11 04:15:28.531 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageButton.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageIcon
12-11 04:15:28.531 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16581: Landroid/widget/ImageButton;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
12-11 04:15:28.531 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-11 04:15:28.532 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
12-11 04:15:28.532 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 707: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-11 04:15:28.532 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.532 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
12-11 04:15:28.532 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 709: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-11 04:15:28.532 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-11 04:15:28.535 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.538 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.539 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.545 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.549 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
12-11 04:15:28.549 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 214 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
12-11 04:15:28.549 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
12-11 04:15:28.557 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16881: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16882: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.567 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16883: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16884: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16885: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
12-11 04:15:28.568 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16929: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16930: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16931: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
12-11 04:15:28.569 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-11 04:15:28.575 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
12-11 04:15:28.575 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16883: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
12-11 04:15:28.575 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0197
12-11 04:15:28.578 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
12-11 04:15:28.578 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15352: Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
12-11 04:15:28.578 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
12-11 04:15:28.580 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.isInLayout, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.setRawTextSize
12-11 04:15:28.580 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16920: Landroid/widget/TextView;.isInLayout ()Z
12-11 04:15:28.580 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
12-11 04:15:28.599 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.610 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.639 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.644 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.647 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.649 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.652 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.655 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/AbsListView: checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
12-11 04:15:28.656 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/skia: Flag is not 10
12-11 04:15:28.753 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
12-11 04:15:28.794 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
12-11 04:15:28.802 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
12-11 04:15:28.869 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-11 04:15:28.885 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
12-11 04:15:28.885 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon
12-11 04:15:28.885 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16619: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
12-11 04:15:28.885 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-11 04:15:31.511 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#1810100
12-11 04:15:31.511 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{418e4dd8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-800,1216} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41a72b08 controlFlags=#104
12-11 04:15:31.514 2973-2973/tech.dalvandi.dataplay1 V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{null com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME #2}
```

Comment: did you check the logcat of your device? copy and paste on your answer

Comment: just my dumb guessing, have like this before and my phone is going with proxy to my host pc, to peek my api, maybe u same :)

Comment: 1.check the data balance, 2.Did you check it on some other mobile device?

Comment: @VigneswaranA I checked on multiple devices, but what do you mean by checking data balance?

Comment: @diegoveloper I edited and added logcat. Thanks!

Comment: Which is the url that you are trying to connect?

Comment: @diegoveloper it is "http://api20171209025511.azurewebsites.net/api/values/all/2017-12-08" the last piece after slash is a parameter and can be a different, but it is a date & time anyway.

Comment: What android version are you using on  your emulator and on your android device?

Comment: On the device I have 4.2.2, and the emulator android 8.

Comment: @diegoveloper Hey I just realized it is an android version issue. Even on an emulator v=with version 4.2.2 I don't get it working. Any idea about the reason?

Comment: Hmm put some code

Comment: @diegoveloper thanks buddy, I found the issue, and the end of the URL I would supply a string parameter. If there is a space inside it, it does not work in older Android versions! As silly as that...

Comment: No problem :) sometimes you find the error explaining it to someone